# What's the solution to this complex number puzzle from Crystal Mentality?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence

I've been racking my brain over a puzzle that appears in Chapter 11 of Crystal Mentality (Loc 2344). If anyone's willing to have a crack at it, I'd love to see what the solution is.

I've included the paragraph that precedes the puzzle below, just in case it offers up a clue of some sort. On its face, this shouldn't include any narrative spoilers, but I can't say the same for the solution to the puzzle!

> "It took, again, a remarkably long time for my brother to respond. {I
>   am not Dream, but I will reflect him for a moment,} he thought. His
>   thoughts became English. {Caesar, caesar, burning bright. Here she is,
>   watch her fight! The foes are numerous and doubtless strong. She cuts
>   them down all day long! But swords are not the caesar's foe.
>   *Justice*... protects her... does *this* she know?} Along with the poem, Growth shared a collection of complex numbers expressed in
>   decimal in a 3x3x3 cube."

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|} \hline
\hline
 0 &  85.1 & 85.2 \\ \hline
 73.1i & 2+2i & -1-1i \\ \hline
 73.2i & -1-1i & 1+1i \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\hline
        0 & 85.1 & 85.2 \\ \hline
        73.1i & 2+2i & 3 \\ \hline
        73.2i & 3i & 1+i \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\hline
        0 & 85.1 & 85.2 \\ \hline
        73.1i & 1-i & -1+i \\ \hline
        73.2i & -1+i & 1-i \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Wait... Where is the question? What should we answer?

Comment: is this some kind of jeopardy question/answer? I mean the numbers you listed represent the solution and I'm supposed to find the question?

Comment: It might be helpful to include why this is a puzzle. To me, it looks like a paragraph and the complex number table it describes, but it does not indicate that there is any work to be done here or what goal we should be striving towards.

Comment: It's odd that different representations of the same number are used ($1+1i$ vs. $1+i$). This makes it unlikely to truly be a number sequence.